# jQuery - Populating drop down form option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm able to populate the names of option fields for the `#maplist` select dropdown:

```
$.each(mapsArray, function(x,y) {

    $.each(y, function(j,z) { 

        $('#maplist').append(

            $('<option></option>').html(z.mapName)

        );
    });
});
```

But I can't figure out how to add `.val` to each option field (in this case, it would be `z.mapID.$id`)

Comment: `.attr('value',z.mapID.$id);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way rather than concatenating a bunch of strings.

```
$.each(mapsArray, function(x,y) {
    $.each(y, function(j,z) { 
       $('#maplist').append(
          $('<option></option>').val(z.mapName).text(z.mapName);
       );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(mapsArray, function(x,y) {

    $.each(y, function(j,z) { 

        $('#maplist').append(

            $('<option value="'+ z.mapName +'">'+ z.mapName +'</option>');

        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .attr():

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

```
$.each(mapsArray, function(x,y) {
    $.each(y, function(j,z) { 
        $('#maplist').append(
            $('<option></option>').html(z.mapName).attr('value', z.mapID.$id);
        );
    });
});
```